# Why SDK Tools are disabled in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Why **SDK Tools** are disabled in Android Studio?

[image]

Version of Android Studio is 2.3.

Comment: I also experience this, with v2.2.3.

Comment: @Nestor, it seems my version of Android Studio was incorrect, the problem was solved by reinstalling Android Studio. And during installing I selected the option "install with imbedded sdk", and now SDK Tools became enabled.

Comment: Interesting how to solve this problem without reinstalling Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my version of Android Studio was incorrect, the problem was solved by reinstalling Android Studio. And during installing I selected the option "install with imbedded sdk", and now SDK Tools became enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that **Android SDK Location** points to correct address where SDK is stored on your system.

Comment: Since you are getting a warning "Android SDK location should not contain whitespace..." , there must be something wrong with the path specified.

Comment: I also have that warning (which is so 1977...really, a whitespace is a problem in 2017 - at the default program install location?), but compiling works so the SDK is there. I also can't start the external SDK Manager.